# Does the ASCII code with the parity bit allow us to correct a one-bit error and recover the original data?

Tags: ascii, parity

Does the ASCII code with the parity bit allow us to correct a one-bit error and does the ASCII code recover the original data?

Comment: No, a parity bit doesn't provide any information about which bit was flipped.  Also what's up with the tag?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the ASCII code with the parity bit allow us to correct a one-bit error

No.  It can only **detect** a 1-bit error.